# Is there a way to attach an abelian variety to $\mathbb{P}^{1} - \{n \text{ points}\}$ (or sm.pr. curve)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a wild guess, but I can not find anything in the literature. (Probably I do not know the right terms to search for.) Please bear with me.

> I am looking for some way to assign a smooth projective curve (or an abelian variety, e.g. the Jacobian of the curve) to $\mathbb{P}^{1} - \{n \text{ points}\}$.

## Motivation

Over $\mathbb{C}$, if one takes $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ and pinches together $g$ pairs of points, this looks pretty much like a surface with $g$ handles, except that all the handles are contracted to 1 point, resulting in singularities. If we remove the singularities, we obtain $\mathbb{P}^{1} - \{2g \text{ points}\}$.

Besides that (or maybe: on the other hand), the fundamental groups of $\mathbb{P}^{1} - \{2g + 1 \text{ points}\}$ and a surface with $g$ handles seem related.

I realise that this is all very topological, and ignores all algebro-geometric data. Nevertheless, maybe something like this is possible.

## Question

So I guess my question boils down to:

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $S \subset \mathbb{P}^{1}(k)$ be a finite set of cardinality $n$. Is there an algebro-geometric method to assign an abelian variety $A/k$ to $\mathbb{P}^{1} - S$?
>
> If yes, please give some indication of how canonical the method is.

**Notes:**

- The reason I ask for an abelian variety, is that if it is possible to assign a curve, we can take the Jacobian. However, maybe it is not possible to assign a curve in a canonical way, but there might still be a method to reach an abelian variety (in some way I currently do not see…).
- I would already be interested in the situation for $k = \mathbb{C}$, however ultimately I am interested in the situation for $k$ of characteristic $p > 0$.

Comment: If $n\ge 2$, you can consider the Albanese variety of the complement of your $n$ points. It is a torus of dimension $n-1$. I don't see a canonical way to associate an abelian variety. The topological construction you describe consists in deforming a projective singular curve, but the resulting Riemann surface is not canonical (for the complex analytic structure) at all.

Comment: @cant_log – Thanks for the comment. I indeed feared that it was not possible get a canonical Riemann surface. Now your comment about the Albanese is very interesting. I had not thought of it, and will look into the details soon.

Comment: What about taking the hyperelliptic cure branched at those points? This would be a canonical construction.

Comment: @RobertAuffarth – Would you please elaborate on this? Or maybe you have a reference to some literature? It would be extremely helpful if the construction works in char $p > 0$.

Comment: If your points are $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ then the curve $y^2=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-p_i)$ (actually the projective closure of this affine curve) is hyperelliptic and branched over the $p_i$. Here I'm assuming that $p_i\neq\infty$, but you can make it work even if there is a $p_i$ equal to $\infty$.

Comment: This is more of a way to assign to the $n$ points a curve/abelian variety; I'm not quite sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Why not the Jacobian for the 2-fold branched cover over $P^1$ ramified over the given points.

Comment: Dear studiosus, this is the same curve I give above.

Comment: @RobertAuffarth – Thanks! (Problem is that I am also not quite sure what I am looking for...) But now I have two constructions (Albanese; hyperelliptic cover branched over $S$) that I can study.

Comment: Actually I can be a bit more precise in what I am looking for: I don't know if it is to optimistic, but I would like to study the $H^{1}$ of $\mathbb{P}^{1} - S$ via this other curve/abelian variety. Just like one uses the usual Jacobian in the case of a smooth projective curve. But probably I am too optimistic here.